# Copying blobs to Azure customized VM's on boot

Tags: linux, azure, startup-scripts

As I'm looking to take advantage of the SSD disks offering (D type in Azure), I understood that the only way to use them, is to copy the data to attached SSD disks from external storage like blob.

I have customized an Ubuntu image, and now looking for a way to copy this data on VM's start-ups.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Via standard Linux means (e.g. init script), or there is a better and faster measure provided by Azure?

Comment: Another option I thought of, is have the data in docker image, however I'm not sure whether dockers already work with the SSD type

Answer (score 0):

One can use the [Custom Script extension](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/20/automate-linux-vm-customization-tasks-using-customscript-extension/) for automating tasks.